# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.get returned null

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

I have a simple LINQ query as follows. However, it is throwing an error while executing.

```
var contactData = await _context.Contacts.Where(x => x.ContactId == 1234).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.get
> returned null

I was assuming, the error occurs because of the open connection. However, I tried closing dbcontext connection before this query. Still it throws same error.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here. Searching the stackoverflow did not help.